# Hide <br /> tag from textarea

Tags: javascript

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function replaceNewlines(e) {
       var element = document.getElementById('myTextarea');

       if (e.keyCode == 13) {
          element.value = element.value.replace("\r", "<br />");
          element.value += "___NEWLINE___\n";
          element.value = element.value.replace("___NEWLINE___\n", "<br />");
       }
    }
</script>
```

This code works fine but when I press enter, `<br />` appears in the `textarea` and I don't want to appear this in my `textarea`.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Welcome to SO ! Could you add a JSFiddle for such questions? It's easier to fix that way!

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to replace new lines with `<br />`, or replace `<br />` with a new line?

Comment: Textareas need a line feed in order to display a line feed, not an html `<br>` tag.  Instead, replace with `"\r\n"`

Comment: If you want a textarea to generate html you should probably use an existing `WYSIWYG` editor like tinymce or ckeditor.

Comment: ... This makes no sense. It's *your code* that is injecting `<br />`. If you don't want them, delete your code which injects them.

Answer (score 1):

So, how about replacing `<br />` with a new line?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function replaceNewlines(e) {
       var element = document.getElementById('myTextarea');

       element.value = element.value.replace(/<br\s*\/?>/g, '\n');
    }
</script>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/tkR9S/ for a full demo.

Comment: How many `<br />` will this replace in the output?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum All of them.

Comment: Not working your code. wait 1 minute to show you

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/uafm028o5/ I want to hide <br />  tag

Comment: @user3248759: But as noted by megar under your post, why insert them in the first place? It's a bit hard to get what you actually are trying to accomplish (overall).

Comment: @user3248759 Please see http://jsfiddle.net/tkR9S/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/durduliu2009/GwD46/ in this code appear '<br />'  in textarea but i don't want to appear <br /> like facebook when you give a comment and press enter not appear '<br />' tag but <br /> is working

Comment: @user3248759 See http://jsfiddle.net/GwD46/1/. And **please** do not paste the `<script>` tags into the script area. Only the script content!

Comment: like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/durduliu2009/GwD46/2/

Comment: @user3248759 Can you explain **what** you want to do, please?

Comment: I want to hide '<br />' tag from textarea. I show you an image too postimg.org/image/uafm028o5

Comment: @user3248759: You need to change "onLoad" to "No wrap - in Head" in your fiddle.

Comment: i don't have onLoad in my code

Comment: @user3248759: In the menu on left side. Change to <head> or <body>.

Comment: @user13500 Do you understand what the questioner wants? I don't.

Comment: At facebook when you add a comment to your post and press enter du add new line <br /> tag don't appear.I Wan't like that

Comment: @user3248759 What browser are you using that adds a `<br />` tag to the `<textarea>`? Firefox doesn't.

Comment: @user3248759 You want **what** for "chrome"? What do you mean by "chrome"?

Comment: @toothbrush: No, I'm not getting it.